# Will the OR statement in if check only one condition? Balanced Bracket

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

I am doing Balanced Bracket using stack. I need to display "Success" if it matches or else output the index(1-indexing) of the first mismatch.

I used `stack<pair <char,int>>stk; string s;` for storing opening bracket ('{' '(' '[') and the index of the bracket. (I stored index for cases like these "[{}" where the mismatch is opening bracket rather than closing one.

```
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
{
    if(s[i]=='{' || s[i]=='[' || s[i]=='(')
    {
    stk.push(make_pair(s[i],i+1));
    }
    else if(!stk.empty() && (s[i]=='}' && stk.top().first=='{') || 
    (s[i]==')' && stk.top().first=='(') || (s[i]==']' && 
    stk.top().first=='['))
    {
    stk.pop();
    }
    else if(!stk.empty() && (s[i]=='}' && stk.top().first!='{') || 
    (s[i]==')' && stk.top().first!='(') || (s[i]==']' && 
    stk.top().first!='['))
    {
    ans=(i+1);
    cout<<ans;
    break;
    }
    else if(stk.empty()&&(s[i]=='}'||s[i]==')'||s[i]==']'))
    {
    ans=i+1;
    cout<<ans;
    break;
    }
}

if(stk.empty() && ans==0)
{
cout<<"Success";
}
if(!stk.empty() && ans==0)
{
cout<<stk.top().second;
}
```

I am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) whenever the first character of string is one of the closing brackets( ')' or ']' ). Its working when input is '}' but now when ')' or ']'

Comment: What is the definition of `stk` and `s`? Can you create a full example which segfaults?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  No i meant```stk.empty()```. This is for cases when the first character is closing bracket. So the stack is empty as i push only opening brackets. Its working when its '}' and not for other two brackets. Doesnt make sense because it defined using OR.

Comment: Ok, I got `s` and `stk` confused with each other. I though you were checking if `s` was empty.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question

> Will the OR statement in if check only one condition? Balanced Bracket

is in this quote of the C++ 20 Standard (7.6.15 Logical OR operator)

> 1 The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (7.3). The result is true if either of
>   its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, || guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; **moreover, the second operand is not
>   evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true**.

After the first operand that is true all other operands do not evaluate.

For example if this condition `s[i]=='}'` evaluates to true then other conditions

```
s[i]==')'  
s[i]==']'
```

are not checked.

You can also rewrite the if statement

```
else if ( stk.empty() && ( s[i] == '}' || s[i] == ')' || s[i] == ']' ) )
```

like

```
else if ( stk.empty() and ( s[i] == '}' or s[i] == ')' or s[i] == ']' ) )
```

As for the segmentation error then either `i` is an invalid index or the reason of the error lies in some other code.

Comment: No i meant if stack is empty(which implies no corresponding opening bracket) AND if its any of the closing brackets then output its index(i+1). In the input I gave it was ')' so it doesn't satisfy first condition in ```(s[i]=='}' || s[i]==')' || s[i]==']')``` so it has to check ```s[i]==')'``` but it gives segmentation fault